# How can an ideal motor do any work when the average of instantaneous power over one cycle is zero?

Tags: reactive-power, calculus

The attached screenshot illustrates the instantaneous power delivered to a purely inductive load as a function of time. How does an ideal motor (or perhaps some other purely inductive load) do any work when the average instantaneous power delivered to the load over one cycle is zero?

[image: p23 of Power Systems Analysis by Grainger/Stevenson/Chang]
Source: p23 of Power Systems Analysis by Grainger/Stevenson/Chang

Comment: Who said the motor remains fully inductive under load?

Comment: Ah okay interesting didn't know about that. Forget the motor, then -- I guess I would rephrase my question as "how can a purely inductive load do any work"?

Comment: a purely inductive load doesn't do any work - all the energy that flows into it in one part of the cycle flows out in the other part of the cycle. All the power is "imaginary". In order for work to be output, some of the power must not be imaginary (i.e. the load must become not purely inductive)

Comment: Consider a perfect inductor (i.e. no resistance). In one part of the cycle a magnetic field is created, and in the other part the magnetic field "goes away" - if nothing nearby perturbs (or is perturbed by) that field, then no work is done by the system

Comment: @BeB00 And if something nearby is perturbed by the field, that coupling means that it's no longer purely inductive.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that an ideal transformer is a purely inductive load?

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training If the transformer's secondary is unloaded, yes. If the secondary is loaded, no.

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training: The question is already fixed. It can't be forgotten. Please if you want to ask a different question, post another question so it can be answered properly.

Comment: Okay will do going forward, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 5):

Any purely inductive load will consume zero net power and do zero work.

However, an ideal motor is only purely inductive if it's unloaded. When the motor has a mechanical load applied, it will show a resistance as well.